# JPA Query don't find EntityClass

Tags: jpa

Well, i'm trying to execute a simple query but i always got a "Not Mapped Entity". See my query :

```
"SELECT c FROM MyOwnClass c WHERE c.filter = :filter ORDER BY c.filter";
```

But if i put the qualified name of class "br.com.myproject.MyOwnClass" the query is executed.

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" name="myPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>br.com.myproject.MyOwnClass</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your entity classes in a different package than your query code?  You probably just need to add an import:

import br.com.myproject.MyOwnClass;

Comment: Yes, it's in different package, but i have anothers examples that works very well in different packages. I don't think this is the problem.